# Libgdx: Stage only renders at (0, 0)

Tags: libgdx

I'm attempting to use LibGDX Stage for my GUI elements, but I'm having loads of difficulty getting it to render properly.  Right now, I'm attempting to render a chat window in the lower left corner of the screen.

Here is the construction of the GUI objects:

```
stage = new Stage();
stage.setCamera(controller.getCamera());

uiSkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("res/gui/skin/uiskin.json"));

Table table = new Table(uiSkin);
stage.addActor(table);

table.setSize(300, 260);
table.setPosition(0, 0);
table.setFillParent(false);
table.bottom();
table.left();
table.pad(10);

lblChatLabel = new Label("", uiSkin);
lblChatLabel.setWrap(true);

final ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(lblChatLabel, uiSkin);

txtChatBar = new TextField("do a chat", uiSkin);
txtChatBar.setName("txtChatBar");

table.add(txtChatBar).width(300f);
table.row();
table.add(scroll).expand().fill().colspan(4);

txtChatBar.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public boolean keyDown(InputEvent event, int keycode) {
        if (keycode == Input.Keys.ENTER) {
            sendMessage();
            // Close the chat bar
            showChat = false;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

And here is my render() method:

```
Log.debug("void", "x: " + stage.getCamera().position.x + ", y: " + stage.getCamera().position.y);
stage.act();
for (Actor a : stage.getActors()) {
    a.draw(spriteBatch, 1);
}
```

In another section of code elsewhere, the game's camera object is translated to center on the player:

```
camera.translate(targetPosition.x, targetPosition.y);
camera.update();
```

So that all said, the chat window renders properly, but it only does so at 0, 0.  I've also changed called stage.draw() rather than iterate through the Actors individually, but that causes the same issue.  Here is a screenshot illustrating the issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHLgl.jpg

Finally, I've tried to translate the stage manually by setting the viewport, but that causes an even weirder issue.

```
float cx = controller.getCamera().getX();
float cy = controller.getCamera().getY();
float width = controller.getCamera().viewportWidth;
float height = controller.getCamera().viewportHeight;
stage.act();
stage.setViewport(width, height, true, cx, cy, width, height);
stage.draw();
```

Image here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR00J.jpg

Certainly I am doing something wrong, but I have no idea at this point.  I would have assumed that the stage follows the Camera translation, but that doesn't appear to be the case.  Any suggestions are welcome!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is this line of code:

```
stage.setCamera(controller.getCamera());
```

If I'm reading correctly, you want the chat window to always render from (0,0), no matter where the camera is on the screen. If that's the case, then the stage shouldn't have any relation with the camera, which moves around and just further complicates getting the stage in the right position to be rendered properly.

Without that line of code, you should be able to just call

```
stage.act();
stage.draw();
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, it is always rendering at 0,0 for the coordinate system in the game and I want it to move with the camera (the first image above shows the box rendering at 0,0 while the player has moved elsewhere). Perhaps that is the issue though, since the GUI stage needs to render in relation to the window, and not the in game coordinates.

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I meant. The above code should always render at 0,0 in window coordinates.